# Error when deploying legacy application to Websphere Liberty

Tags: java-ee-6, websphere-liberty

I'm having issues when trying to deploy a somewhat legacy application to Websphere Liberty to facilitate development.

The application runs fine in regular Websphere Server 8.5.5 but won't start in Websphere Liberty. We have another legacy application based on mostly the same technologies/frameworks that runs ok. Unfortunatelöy we won't move to a newer platform anytime soon.

I have the following features configured for my server:

```
<featureManager>
        <feature>localConnector-1.0</feature>
        <feature>jpa-2.0</feature>
        <feature>jsf-2.0</feature>
        <feature>jdbc-4.0</feature>
        <feature>servlet-3.0</feature>
        <feature>ejbLite-3.1</feature>
        <feature>cdi-1.0</feature>
    <feature>appSecurity-1.0</feature>
        
    </featureManager>
```

When I try to start it I get an exception during annotation processing:

```
[VARNING ] CWNEN0047W: Resource annotations on the fields of the xxx.xxx.EditCardGroupBacking class will be ignored. The annotations could not be obtained because of the exception : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.resource.spi.IllegalStateException
```

whiich seems strange since this would be a part of the JRE?

I have searched various forums/pages for an answer but can't faind the answer. Hopefully someone here can be of assistance.

I'm happy to provide more details of configuration and setup if needed.

Answer (score 3):

`javax.resource.spi.IllegalStateException` is part of the JCA (Java EE Connector Architecture) specification (see [JavaDoc here](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/resource/spi/IllegalStateException.html)). You do not get it automatically from Java. Try enabling the jca-1.6 feature,

```
<feature>jca-1.6</feature>
```

FYI - if anyone else hits this who has newer level Java EE features, they would instead need:

```
<feature>jca-1.7</feature>
```